# How can I draw on JPanel using another quadrant for the coordinates?

Tags: java, coordinates, java-2d, graphics2d, affinetransform

I would like to draw some shapes on a JPanel by overriding `paintComponent`. I would like to be able to pan and zoom. Panning and zooming is easy to do with `AffineTransform` and the `setTransform` method on the `Graphics2D` object. After doing that I can easyli draw the shapes with `g2.draw(myShape)` The shapes are defined with the "world coordinates" so it works fine when panning and I have to translate them to the canvas/JPanel coordinates before drawing.

Now I would like to change the [quadrant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system#Two-dimensional_coordinate_system) of the coordinates. From the 4th quadrant that JPanel and computer often uses to the 1st quadrant that the users are most familiar with. The X is the same but the Y-axe should increase upwards instead of downwards. It is easy to redefine origo by `new Point(origo.x, -origo.y);`

**But How can I draw the shapes in this quadrant?** I would like to keep the coordinates of the shapes (defined in the world coordinates) rather than have them in the canvas coordinates. So I need to transform them in some way, or transform the `Graphics2D` object, and I would like to do it **efficiently**. Can I do this with `AffineTransform` too?

My code for drawing:

```
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
            g2.setColor(Color.blue);

            AffineTransform at = g2.getTransform();
            at.translate(-origo.x, -origo.y);
            at.translate(0, getHeight());
            at.scale(1, -1);
            g2.setTransform(at);
            g2.drawLine(30, 30, 140, 20);
            g2.draw(new CubicCurve2D.Double(30, 65, 23, 45, 23, 34, 67, 58));
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an off the cuff answer, so it's untested, but I think it will work.

Translate by (0, height). That should reposition the origin to the lower left.

Scale by (1, -1). That should flip it about the x axis.

I don't think the order of operations matters in this case.