# HTML5 Canvas (inverted) coordinate system

Tags: html, canvas

I am new to Canvas, and wonder:

1. the rationale of using inverted cartesian coordinate system.
2. Say, I need to chart some values in histogram. Is an easy way to rotate/map a canvas frame to cartesian coordinate system.?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563618/how-can-i-draw-on-jpanel-using-another-quadrant-for-the-coordinates

Comment: thought the post you showed is not on canvas, I will try similar technique. thanks for the link

Comment: I added my link as an answer now.

Comment: EVERYthing in the PC world has Y increasing downward  ...it's not just <canvas>. Framebuffers are built that way, displays are built that way, etc...

Comment: Hold on so CSS has X and Y zero BOTH in the upper left however <canvas> only has Y as zero in the upper left however X as zero on the upper right?  Kinda odd.  Perhaps there is a way to change this with a <canvas> context variable?

Comment: It maybe is best to just use a <canvas> (x,y) transform.  http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/2dcontext/html5_canvas/#transformations

Comment: @VSH Huh? <canvas> has X zero on the upper right??? I don't think so. Can you point us to the source of that information?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Canvases are inverted because it is intuitive to a lot of interfaces. Web pages are more like a sheet of paper than a cartesian graph, because you start at the top left and read down. Therefore, html is laid out like that. I assume the canvas element uses the same coordinate system for consistency.

You can flip it by scaling the y axis by -1. You might need to transform it as well, i'm not sure about that, but there's a comment on your question that should help with that. The transforming functions are pretty much the same in html as they are in that post.

I use the html5 standard draft a lot for reference. Here's some content from the [canvas 2d context section](http://dev.w3.org/html5/2dcontext/):

```
void scale(in double x, in double y);
void rotate(in double angle);
void translate(in double x, in double y);
void transform(in double a, in double b, in double c, in double d, in double e, in double f);
void setTransform(in double a, in double b, in double c, in double d, in double e, in double f);
```

Comment: In my experience the coordinate system for a <canvas> is the _same_ as the coordinate system for everything else related to PCs: browsers, pages, screens, etc. I've never run across any need  to "flip" any axis at all. In other words, if <canvas>es are indeed inverted, it's news to me.

Comment: The canvas coordinate system is inverted relative to what the OP expects, probably from working in 3D, for example, where y often (but not always) points up, or in most high school and some college-level math classes where the positive Y axis is, again, pointing up. I suppose either could be called "inverted" depending on where you come from.

Comment: Yep, if you refer to other things (such as math class), the coordinates may seem "inverted". But if you stay within the world of computer graphics, there's _no_ inversion. In this particular case, the inference that "canvas" is inverted with respect to other kinds of computer graphics simply isn't true.

Comment: The orientation of the coordinate system for most computer applications is derived from the underlying display technology - only makes sense to process data in the manner and order it will be displayed. Diving into the history of the monitor will lead you through [CRT displays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathode_ray_tube), the [history of television](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Television#History), and eventually to the standard [raster scanning pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raster_scan#Scanning_pattern). Left to right, top to bottom, because that's just how we've always done it.

Comment: Conversion needs to happen if you are using standard geometrical formulas  - for example calculating the point on the canvas with a certain degree of rotation around the center of the canvas.

Answer (score 6):

From [How can I draw on JPanel using another quadrant for the coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563618/how-can-i-draw-on-jpanel-using-another-quadrant-for-the-coordinates)

> Translate by (0, height). That should reposition the origin to the lower left.
>
> Scale by (1, -1). That should flip it about the x axis.

Answer (score 4):

I'm skipping the discussion of what should be considered inverted and non inverted cartesian coordinate system (it is pretty much a matter of what context you first encounter the concept and what conventions were in effect there).

However, the reason HTML canvas (and SVG and many other coordinate systems related to screen rendering) put origo in the top left corner is simply because the CRT screens (which for long time was the dominating computer display technology) rendered the computer display by letting a electron beam sweep over the screen, line by line, until the entire display were rendered. For all CRTs I've heard about, the scan lines were horisontal and were rendered from left to right.  Also, the topmost scan line was rendered first, so the top left corner is where all screen refreshes started.  Letting that corner be origo with X increasing downwards and Y increasing rightwards simplified the calculations for mapping a screen coordinate to video memory positions (and simplified calculations meant simplified hardware in the early days of computer display controllers).  AFAIK, television screens scan their displays in this way as well, starting from the top left corner.

(Arcade games were a bit inventive in this respect, quite a few of them took a "normal" computer CRT, and then had it rotated 90 degrees to get a screen which were better suited to the layout of the video game being produced.  For those games the screen refreshes did not start in the top left corner, for obvious reasons.)

This convention to put origo at top left and let X increase downwards and Y rightwards has stuck since those early days and seems to be used in all kinds of computer graphic contexts.

But I agree, mathematical X/Y graphs are oriented otherwise, especially with X being positive upwards.

As @franticfantom says, you can use the transformation features of the HTML Canvas API to do a scale of -1 in the Y direction to mirror the graph to be upside down and then use a translation to move origo from top left to wherever you like.  Be aware that such a scale -1 transformation will mirror everything, so just applying that to any text you use in your graphs will just result in mirrored or upside down text.  Some care has to be taken to "unreverse" any text in place.

Comment: "X" being positive upwards?  Would you mind going into a little more detail on that?

Comment: @ChrisHagan: I'm pretty sure he has vertical & horizontal swapped throughout this answer.

Comment: The convention for most fields of math/science is a [right handed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system#Orientation_and_handedness) (+x -> right, +y -> up) system, so the `canvas` (and most other systems in the computer world) coordinates are indeed "inverted". Though not all - for example, [PDFs](https://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v19/dh/to/leadtools.topics.pdf~pdf.topics.pdfcoordinatesystem.html) (and many apps focused on print media) use a standard right-hand system with the origin at the lower left corner.